# Python Pandas and Sqlite3 [Value ] not in index

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, matplotlib

Hey I'm new in Python and I need your help.

I want to show the data of my Sqlite database with an diagramm using Pandas(or probalby Bokeh).
But wenn I try to run my script it returns : KeyError: '[18 18 18 18 21] not in index'. I dont know what to do.

The Database:`id hum  temp    time      date

              1  59   18   10:03:06  2020-05-16

              2  59   19   10:04.06  2020-05-16`

So here is my Code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import sqlite3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



con = sqlite3.connect("/home/pi/test2.db")
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from data4 limit 5;",con)

time = df["time"]
temp = df["temp"]


df.plot(x = temp, y = temp, kind ='line')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to give the labels in x and y like this:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('/home/pi/test2.db')
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * from data4 limit 5', con)

df.plot(x='time', y='temp', kind ='line')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me a lot, but how can I show to "hum" data too? So that I have 2 y-axis which show me the data?